# How Can I use Odoo 9 Website features in my odoo v8 online website

Tags: odoo, v8

I have created my website using odoo v8 features , that time v9 was under development

Now in v9 of odoo website , it provides more features than v8 , like graphics , plugins , apps more and advanced than v8 ,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cE83kPzKzkc

I have created my website online in odoo v8 , so how can I use that features in my online website made in v8

Comment: can u explaination in detail ????  migrate ur database in v9 or u make ur custome module about v8

Answer (score 1):

There's an OCA project called OpenUpgrade, go to 
https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade and try it.
and also doc for Open source upgrade https://doc.therp.nl/openupgrade

OR

You can ask the odoo company to do that task for you by going to this link, https://upgrade.odoo.com/database/upload But they will charge money for that. If you can do it yourself here is the documentation on how to do that, https://doc.therp.nl/openupgrade/intro.html